# "not listed in package.json" , node.js while installing NTVS

Tags: node.js, express, dependencies, npm

[image]

In the red box following status  show for the modules.. can anyone  help me.. Thanks advance

Comment: While installing a new package one can do node install --save, it will then automatically update the package.json. More documentation at https://npmjs.org/doc/install.html

Comment: i do this already veere

Comment: Short answer - `npm install <pkg> --save`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open up command prompt and cd into the project directory (you can right-click the project in Solution Explorer and choose `Open command prompt from here...`).

Type `npm init` and fill in the fields when prompted (or hit `Enter` to take the default). The output should look something like this...

```
C:\Anthony\Demo\ExpressApp1\ExpressApp1>npm init
This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file.
It only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sane defaults.

See `npm help json` for definitive documentation on these fields
and exactly what they do.

Use `npm install <pkg> --save` afterwards to install a package and
save it as a dependency in the package.json file.

Press ^C at any time to quit.
name: (ExpressApp1)
version: (0.0.0)
description:
entry point: (app.js)
test command:
git repository:
keywords:
author:
license: (ISC)
About to write to C:\Anthony\Demo\ExpressApp1\ExpressApp1\package.json:

{
  "name": "ExpressApp1",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~3.4.4",
    "jade": "~1.1.5",
    "stylus": "~0.42.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}


Is this ok? (yes)
```

If for some reason `npm init` doesn't work, you can save the following text into a file called `package.json` in the root of your project and update the values to match the packages in your project.

```
{
  "name": "ExpressApp1",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~3.4.4",
    "jade": "~1.1.5",
    "stylus": "~0.42.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

A third option is to delete the `npm_modules` folder in the project. Then you can right click on the `npm` "folder" in Solution Explorer, select `Manage npm modules...`, and reinstall the packages. Installing them this way should create a `package.json` for you.

Comment: Press ^C at any time to quit.  upto this the console gives the same code... but aftr this there are couple off errors.. like
npm err...

Comment: If all else fails, you should be able to copy everything inside the {}'s above, and save it in a file called package.json in your project (modifying for your values, of course). All `npm init` does is help you fill in that file to list out the dependencies in your project... but all it really does is spit out the text file. What are the errors?

Comment: should you create our discussion so solve this accuratly

Comment: Answer updated with the alternative solutions. Let me know if those work for you.